# Setting background image as prop in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that needs to take in a background image from the parent `Play` component, not set in the stylesheet. I'm trying to pass it as a prop to the component, but not sure quite sure how to get this working:

**Main component**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import DeviceBlock from '/DeviceBlock/DeviceBlock'

const Play = {
  init() {
    const container = document.getElementById('blocker-container');
    if(container) {
      ReactDOM.render(
        <DeviceBlock
        backgroundImage={'background-image-url.png'}
        logo={'url-to-logo.png'} />,
        container
      )
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  Play.init()
})
```

**Blocking component imported into above Play component**

```
import React from 'react'
import './DeviceBlock.scss'

function DeviceBlock (props) {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      backgroundImage: backgroundImage,
      logo: logo;
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className='device-blocking' style={this.state.backgroundImage}>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='logo'>
          <img src='{{this.state.logo}}' />
        </div>
        <div className='message'>
          <h1>Content</h1>
          <a href='/' className='btn btn--primary btn--lg'>Link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DeviceBlock
```

Answer (score 16):

You should **import** your background img

```
import BackgroundImage from '...png'; // Relative Path to BackgroundImage
import Logo from '...png'; // Relative Path to Logo
```

and in your state

```
this.state = {
  backgroundImage: `url(${BackgroundImage})`,
  logo: Logo
};
```

Also I noticed that your `<img>` is wrong

`<img src='{{this.state.logo}}' />`

Should be

`<img src={this.state.logo} />`

Also note I saw that you added a constructor inside a function.
If you want to create a react component with state you need to make the component a class.

```
class DeviceBlock extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }
  render() { 
    ...
  }
}
```

> **EDIT:** This is the updated code for your edit based on passing through props.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import DeviceBlock from '/DeviceBlock/DeviceBlock'
import BackgroundImage from '../url-to-background.png'; // Path to BackgroundImage
import Logo from 'url-to-logo.png'; // Relative Path to Logo

const Play = {
  init() {
    const container = document.getElementById('blocker-container');
    if (container) {
      ReactDOM.render(
        <DeviceBlock
          backgroundImage={BackgroundImage}
          logo={Logo} 
        />,
        container
      )
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  Play.init()
})

import * as React from 'react'
import './DeviceBlock.scss'

function DeviceBlock (props) {
  return (
    <div 
      className='device-blocking' 
      style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.backgroundImage})` }}
    >
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='logo'>
          <img src={props.logo} />
        </div>
        <div className='message'>
          <h1>Content</h1>
          <a href='/' className='btn btn--primary btn--lg'>Link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DeviceBlock
```

Note my solution only works if your images are from your own server and processed from webpack and not from another URL.

If the images are from another URL you shouldn't import the URLs and add them directly to the props

```
<DeviceBlock
  backgroundImage="url-to-background.png",
  logo="url-to-logo.png"
/>
```

Comment: I've udpated my question above with the full scope of code for what I'm trying to accomplish, by passing the images from the Play component to the blocker component.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: This helped get me in the right direction, though I had to modify the answer slightly.

Answer (score 5):

Style is an object. Try it like this:

```
style={{backgroundImage: this.state.backgroundImage}}
```

Further, you cannot have a constructor and use state within a functional component. Either turn your component into a regular react component and keep the state, or have the state part in a regular react component and pass it down as props into the functional component. This is also mentioned in the answer by @Kenneth Truong

To turn it into a regular react component you can do the following:

```
class DeviceBlock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      backgroundImage: "url('url-to-background.png')",
      logo: "url('url-to-logo.png')";
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='device-blocking' style={{backgroundImage: this.state.backgroundImage}}>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='logo'>
            <img src='{{this.state.logo}}' />
          </div>
          <div className='message'>
            <h1>Content</h1>
            <a href='/' className='btn btn--primary btn--lg'>Link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You can see it working here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWexzO

UPDATE

Based on the updated question, you can also keep it as a functional component and pass down props:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      backgroundImage: "url('url-to-background.png')",
      logo: "url('url-to-logo.png')";
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <DeviceBlock 
        backgroundImage={this.state.backgroundImage}
        logo={this.state.logo}/>
    )
  }
}

const DeviceBlock = (props) => {
    return (
      <div className='device-blocking' style={{backgroundImage: props.backgroundImage}}>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='logo'>
            <img src='{{props.logo}}' />
          </div>
          <div className='message'>
            <h1>Content</h1>
            <a href='/' className='btn btn--primary btn--lg'>Link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvdPOQ

The app component is simply demonstrating that you can pass down some dynamic state. You can, of course, render the `DeviceBlock` component directly from your `Play.init` function like you do in your provided code (then you can just ignore the App component part).

Comment: You should propably also make this a string: `url('url-to-background-image.png')` => `"url('url-to-background-image.png')"`

Comment: Applied the recommendations and updated code above, but the images are still not loading.

Comment: Did you notice the double curly braces? `<div className='device-blocking' style={this.state.backgroundImage}>` should be `<div className='device-blocking' style={{this.state.backgroundImage}}>`

Comment: Yes, I noticed. Still having issues though.

Comment: Actually this entire syntax looks a bit weird to me.
This is a functional component right? Then you do not have access to state. Either make it a regular react component or pass the backgroundimage and logo down as props

Comment: It’s a presentational component that will be used for another project, so the background image needs to be passed in.

Comment: I have updated my answer with and example on how this could be rewritten

Comment: I've updated the question with the full scope of code to make it clearer what I'm trying to do. I need to be able to pass in the images from the parent Play to the Blocker component.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the images to show in the child component by passing the images into `<DeviceBlock />` in the parent like so:

```
<DeviceBlock
    backgroundImage="background-image-url.png"
    logo="logo-image-url.png" />,
    container
```

and then taking them as props in the child

```
<div className='device-blocking' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.backgroundImage})` }}>
  <div className='container'>
    <div className='logo'>
      <img src={props.logo} />
    </div>
    <div className='message'>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <a href='/' className='btn btn--primary btn--lg'>Link text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```