# Setting background image within React component

Tags: css, reactjs

I am currently fiddeling with this [transformation](https://codesandbox.io/s/k0nozy8nyo?file=/src/index.js) snippet, and I want to change the background of the boxes to images, instead of a gradient. However, it does not seem to work.

```
 <div
          className="element"
                style={{
                width: element.width,
                height: element.height,
                backgroundImage: this.state.backgroundImage,
                ...styles,
                }}
                                        
 >
```

```
import BackgroundImage from './door1.png';
...
...
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            elements: [
                {
                    id: "el-3",
                    x: 100,
                    y: 225,
                    scaleX: 1,
                    scaleY: 1,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    angle: 0,
                    backgroundImage: {BackgroundImage},
                    classPrefix: "tr2",
                    text: "Scale Disabled",
                    styles: {
                        padding: 5,
                    },
                    disableScale: false,
                },
            ],
            offsetX: 40,
            offsetY: 20,
            zoom: 1,
        };

        this.workspaceRef = React.createRef();
    }
```

Any ideas?
I also tried to do something like this:
[Setting Background-Image in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55261748/setting-background-image-in-react) ,
[Syled Components Background Image React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617591/syled-components-background-image-react) ,
[Setting background image as prop in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740341/setting-background-image-as-prop-in-react/49740392)

But it didn't seem to work

I also tried to put it inside the div, like this:

```
<div
    className="element"
    style={{
        width: element.width,
        height: element.height,
        backgroundImage: this.state.backgroundImage,
        ...styles,
    }}
    
>
    <img src={element.backgroundImage.BackgroundImage} />
    {element.text}
</div>
```

but then it ended up looking like this:
[Door](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svqRi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a tiny little modification

change your json objects like

```
...
    backgroundImage: BackgroundImage, //without curly braces
....
```

and in the div

```
    style={{
       ....
       backgroundImage: `url("${element.backgroundImage}")`,
       ...styles
    }}
```

check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-wozniak-6is34)

Comment: Thank you very much @kalhan.toress, Do you by any chance know how to automatically fit the images within the border?

Comment: The image I am trying to display looks like this: https://imgur.com/3caKG1u
When it should look like this: https://imgur.com/YDJCbc4

Comment: @ojbl try to add `background-size: 100% 100%;` style